# Unit Testing AngularJS route with "resolve"

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test one of my routes and I get the infamous "Error: Unexpected request" error. My route takes in a "resolve" parameter and looks like this:

```
when('/Users',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'app/users/user-list.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'UserListCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        userAccounts: ['UserAccounts', function(UserAccounts) {
                            return UserAccounts.query({ id: 123 });
                        }]
                    }
                })
```

where **UserAccounts** is a "resource". I am testing my route as follows:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$route_, _$location_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
        $route = _$route_;
        $location = _$location_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        $httpBackend.when('GET', 'api/Accounts/123/UserAccounts').respond([]);
        $httpBackend.when('GET', 'app/users/user-list.tpl.html').respond({});
    }));

it('/Users should get user-list template and use UserListCtrl', inject(function($controller) {
            $httpBackend.expectGET('app/users/user-list.tpl.html');
            $httpBackend.expectGET('api/Accounts/123/UserAccounts');

            expect($route.current).toBeUndefined();
            $location.path('/Users');
            $rootScope.$digest();

            expect($route.current.loadedTemplateUrl).toBe('app/users/user-list.tpl.html');
            expect($route.current.controller).toBe('UserListCtrl');
    }));
```

And the test fails with `Error: Unexpected request: GET http://myserver/api/Accounts/123/UserAccounts`. This is the get that my resolve is calling. Any ideas what the right way is to test such a route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow! this was a silly one. I had the complete URL defined in my Resource

```
http://myserver/api/Accounts/:accountId/UserAccounts/:userId
```

And I was setting up expectation on my `$httpBackend` to check for relative paths.

```
api/Accounts/123/UserAccounts
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things look strange about your test code.

First, your beforeEach method has the GET requests duplicated with those being called in the actual test. Try removing them.

Second, it looks as if you are missing a call to $httpBacken.flush() before your final assertions.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: The reason i broke the Get requests into two is because I wanted to reuse the same return value from other tests. The $httpbackend.flush did not help just like I presumed. It would help if i was testing the controller but I am testing the routes here. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You can try mocking the service

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('UserAccounts', {
        query: angular.noop
    });
}));
```

If you care whether the service method has been called, you can create a spy.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(UserAccounts, 'query');
});
```

Comment: I had previously tried mocking the service but that didnt help either. I started getting "Request unsatisfied" errors when I mocked the service. I finally found the issue and it was really silly.

Answer (score 0):

To unit test resolved values of a route:

var resolvedUserAccounts = $injector.invoke($route.current.$$route.resolve.userAccounts);